# Custom html helper in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I used extension method and wrote a drop-down list, Now I want to get the selected value from view and pass to controller. How can do it?

```
public static MvcHtmlString DayDropDownCalender(this HtmlHelper helper)
{        
    TagBuilder daydropdown = new TagBuilder("select");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; ++i)
    {
        var option = new TagBuilder("option");
        option.SetInnerText(i.ToString());
        option.MergeAttribute("value", i.ToString());
        daydropdown.InnerHtml += option.ToString();
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(daydropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give your `<select>` element a `name` attribute:

```
TagBuilder daydropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
daydropdown.Attributes["name"] = "day";
```

and then your `[HttpPost]` controller action could simply take it as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string day)
{
    ... the day parameter will contain the selected value
}
```

or if you want to pass more than a simple scalar value to the controller action you would simply design a view model that will contain all the information needed:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

that your controller action will take:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```